# com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized

Tags: soap, jboss

I am running a sample program on SOAP web service on ecplise with jboss.
In Web Service Tester, when I gave the wsdl url and clicked "invoke" button, i am getting the following error:

***com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.ClientTransportException: The server sent HTTP status code 401: Unauthorized***

please help

Comment: The response code 401 means unauthorized - Is the web service secured by username/apssword? What happens if you try to load the wsdl with a webbrowser? Would you please add the code of the sample web service and all relevant configurations (e.g. web.xml)? You should never post questions without the code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. There was some port no issue and after changing the port no the issue was resolved .

Answer (score 0):

I got to similar problem. Several things can go wrong.
1) If you are testing something, the system performing the testing could have blacklisted or non whitelisted IP. 
2) If there is a mysql backend handling the request you might need to update the previleges for the mysql.